# Запрос SQL в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Есть такой запрос SQL

```sql
SELECT e.Date, SUM(e.Amount) FROM Expenses.Expenses e
WHERE e.Date BETWEEN '20190801' AND '20190831'
GROUP BY DAY(e.Date), e.Date
```

Как его можно написать с помощью Linq на C#?

Пробовал так:

```cs
var model = _expenses.GetAll();
model.Where(d => d.Date >= dateSE.Item1 && d.Date <= dateSE.Item2)
     .GroupBy(s => new {s.Date.Day, s.Amount}, 
     (key, group) => new {Day = key, item = group.ToList()});
```

Но как сделать `SUM(e.Amount)` не пойму.

Comment: `GROUP BY DAY(e.Date), e.Date` не имеет смысла - либо достаточно `GROUP BY e.Date`, либо необходимо `GROUP BY DAY(e.Date)` (но тогда почему `e.Date` в выходном наборе?).

Comment: @Akina Мне нужно что бы сортировал по дням, но выводил дату полостью, если убрать из GROUP BY (e.Date) ругается что (`Столбец "Expenses.Expenses.Date" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.`)

Comment: `.Select(a => new { a.Day.Date, Sum = a.item.Sum(b => b.Amount) })`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Спасибо! Хотя код, так и не заработал как нужно :).